# Customize run java project command in intelij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I deployed the jar file on the tomcat server and typed the below command for running the application.

```
java -cp projectname.jar com.example.main config.xml
```

Now I want to use IntelliJ to run and deploy but IntelliJ is not recognizing the main file and config.
How can I fix it?

Comment: `Jar` file in tomcat? That confuses me. You deploy `war` files to a web appllication server like tomcat. Read https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-deploy-a-JAR-file-to-Tomcat-the-right-way .

So, do you relly need a tomcat or is this just about running a java application? 

Do you have a play button as a gutter icon at the main method line?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem with my application. I was using maven and when I tried running the jar file there was this same error. I fixed it by using correct jar file name. I noticed in my app there was 2 jar being generated one of them threw main not found error while the another one worked perfectly.